# IdentityServer4: Not remembering login in live environment

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have a working IdentityServer application working fine locally with a number of websites for API, and a portal for example.  (All using http://localhost:xxxx with different ports)

When I deploy this to the live server it no longer remembers my login and seem to timeout if left for 20 mins, I assume this is something to do with cookies as in the live environment the domains are myaccount.domain.com (IdentityServer) api.domain.com and portal.domain.com so may be a cross domain thing.

Using the Aspnet.Core 1.1 version, hosting is on IIS with a commercial host.

If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated

Thanks
Richard

Comment: See the duplicate question. It's phrased bit differently, but it boils down that IIS recycles your application when it's idle or requires memory. On next start you get new encryption keys. To persist the keys you need to use `AddDataProtection()` to persist the encryption keys where they can be loaded when the application restarts

Comment: @RichardB Are you using the InMemory store for issued tokens, or have you implemented a `IPersistedGrantStore`?

Comment: @Mashton - Yes it is using InMemory at the moment.    That seems to work locally between webserver stopping and starting so guess I need to change that?

Comment: Yes, just implement a `IPersistedGrantStore` and your tokens will now only expire when they reach end of life - not just because the memory of your server has been flushed. It also means you can run more than one server (behind a load balancer for example) and your tokens will be valid whichever server happens to be called upon to verify the token. Have a read of the [deployment](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/topics/deployment.html) section of the docs to make sure you're doing the other things that should be done when going to production suitable code.